# Modify C# Class Library Project To Web Application Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, class-library, vs-web-application-project

Is there a way to easily modify a pre-existing (empty) C# Class Library project to be recognized by Visual Studio as a Web Application project?

Comment: You would need to change a bunch of GUIDs in the .csproj and add/remove some elements to it. Better to just make a new project from scratch.